# OpenVPN to connect remote networks, peer to peer instead of client/server possible?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I would like to connect two remote networks using OpenVPN. I am very new to this we are very small and don't have a sys/network admin. What are the possible setups to have both networks both live on a common LAN via OpenVPN?

I would prefer to use the UDP peer model rather than client/server. Is there a way to set that up instead? I can't see how because no computer on existing network A has a routable address to any computer on existing network B and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The peer to peer feature of OpenVPN, just means either side can initiate the connection.  It doesn't have any method to bypass NATs.

OpenVPN has a very simple protocol, and is very easy to get through a firewall and setup port forwarding for.  On either network you could pick any port, forward that to the system inside the network that will terminate the OpenVPN connection.  Then adjust the configuration to use that port.  By default OpenVPN uses 1194.

You didn't mention what type of routers you have on these two networks, but some routers have a VPN on them.  Or if these are small consumer routers it is likely you could install a firmware on them that will include OpenVPN.  Which you can use to create the VPN from the routers which will have a public address, and will allow you allow access to whole network.

Comment: One is a cisco router which does include a VPN, the other is an actiontec "came with the internet service" dsl-modem/router. I have no idea how would would get a firmware for the actiontec that included OpenVPN. How is that possible?

Comment: Is replacing the Actiontec router with a Cisco router an option?  That may be a better solution, in any cases you should be able to forward the required ports to a device behind the router on either site.